# Using two .change() for two different select

Tags: jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/xv1ozszv

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<center>
    <h3 id="h3A"> </h3>
    <h4> vs </h4>
    <h3 id="h3B"> </h3>
    <h4> 60 - 70 </h4>
</center>
<div class="12u$">
    <div class="select-wrapper">
        <select name="teamA" id="teamA" style="max-width:30%;">
            <option value="">- TeamA -</option>
            <option value="1">Kansas</option>
            <option value="1">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value=4>Texas</option>
            <option value="1">Notre Dame</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="12u$">
    <div class="select-wrapper">
        <select name="teamB" id="teamB" style="max-width:30%;">
            <option value="">- TeamB -</option>
            <option value="1">Kansas</option>
            <option value="1">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="1">Texas</option>
            <option value="1">Notre Dame</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

$("#teamA")
    .change(function() {
        var str = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function() {
            str = $(this).text() + " "; // var of what im changing
        });
        $("#h3A").text(str); // target of what to change
    })
    .change(); // make it happen        
$("#teamB")
    .change(function() {
        var str = "";
        $("select option:selected").each(function() {
            str = $(this).text() + " "; // var of what im changing
        });
        $("#h3B").text(str); // target of what to change
    })
    .change(); // make it happen
```

I am trying to make two selects that change two different texts independently and am having some trouble. Take a look at the fiddle for my code. I think I am on the right track by using the id's but they still dont act completely independently. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be binding the change listener correctly to each select element. However, the event triggered is looking for `$( "select option:selected" )` which will match the selected option from both select lists.

Comment: never mind I fixed it. I replaced "select" with "#teamA"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to associate `<select>` elements with their respective `<h3>` elements.

In my example below, I've given each `<select>` element a `data-team` attribute to match its team letter ("A" or "B"). Then, when a `<select>` element is changed, I use the value of its team attribute to select the `<h3>` element that has the same team attribute.

Also, in this context, note that the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the `<select>` element that has fired the `change` event. For example, `$(':selected',this).text()` refers to the selected option of the changed `<select>` element.

```js
$("select").on('change', function() {
  
  var team = $(this).data('team'),
      str  = $(':selected',this).text(),
      $out = $("h3[data-team=" + team + "]");
  
  $out.text(str);
  
}).change();
```

```css
h3,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
select {
  display: block;
  max-width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#headings {
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="headings">
  <h3 data-team="A">A</h3>
  <h4>vs</h4>
  <h3 data-team="B">B</h3>
  <h4>60 - 70</h4>
</div>

<select data-team="A">
  <option>- TeamA -</option>
  <option>Kansas</option>
  <option>Oklahoma</option>
  <option>Texas</option>
  <option>Notre Dame</option>
</select>
<select data-team="B">
  <option>- TeamB -</option>
  <option>Kansas</option>
  <option>Oklahoma</option>
  <option>Texas</option>
  <option>Notre Dame</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code a bit to show what you can do.

http://jsfiddle.net/xv1ozszv/2/

```
$('#A').change(function(){
```

Adding the onChange event to the ID is better than adding it to all the selects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is even inside your event handlers, you're using too ambiguous of a selector.

Also, there were some bits that could be done more efficiently. I've cleaned it up:

```js
$("#teamA").change(function() {
  $("#h3A").text($(this).children("option:selected").text()); // target of what to change
}).change(); // make it happen      
$("#teamB").change(function() {
  $("#h3B").text($(this).children("option:selected").text()); // target of what to change
}).change(); // make it happen
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <h3 id="h3A"> </h3>
  <h4> vs </h4>
  <h3 id="h3B"> </h3>
  <h4> 60 - 70 </h4>
</center>
<div class="12u$">
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <select name="teamA" id="teamA" style="max-width:30%;">
      <option value="">- TeamA -</option>
      <option value="1">Kansas</option>
      <option value="2">Oklahoma</option>
      <option value="3">Texas</option>
      <option value="4">Notre Dame</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="12u$">
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <select name="teamB" id="teamB" style="max-width:30%;">
      <option value="">- TeamB -</option>
      <option value="1">Kansas</option>
      <option value="2">Oklahoma</option>
      <option value="3">Texas</option>
      <option value="4">Notre Dame</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```